# how to add check box inside a Fragments that effect the main activity

Tags: android

hello guys i tried to add a check box in a fragment but i cant connect it to the main activity so that the check box inside the frag will change the text view inside the main activity

the code i used for Fragment java is

```
 package com.example.eyad.fragwork;


import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;



public class Fragm extends Fragment {

CheckBox c1,c2,c3;
changeT ct;

public Fragm() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
c1=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.c1);
    c2=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.c2);
    c3=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.c3);

    if(c1.isChecked())
        ct.changtxt(c1.getText().toString());
    if(c2.isChecked())
        ct.changtxt(c2.getText().toString());
    if(c3.isChecked())
        ct.changtxt(c3.getText().toString());

    return v;

}
public interface changeT{
    public void changtxt(String S);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ct=(changeT)activity;
}
```

}

and the code for main activity is

```
package com.example.eyad.fragwork;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainFrag extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragm.changeT{
TextView tv;
String w="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_frag);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    tv.setText(w);

}

@Override
public void changtxt(String S) {

    if(S.equals("be happy"))
        w +=S;
    if(S.equals("no worries"))
        w +=S;
    if (S.equals("it will be okay"))
        w +=S;




}
```

}

and there is a pic for the xml mainactivity page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3TKH.png)

thanx all ready

Comment: You need to explain exactly what is wrong with the code. Does it crash, or?

Comment: `changtxt` obviously needs to call `setText` on the `TextView`. And you might want to set a `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` on the  checkboxes to detect every time they're clicked.

Comment: Looking again I think you need to set an onChangeListener on your checkboxes.

Comment: first Thanks for the response .

Comment: first Thanks for the response .and about the problem it is the main idea of the example that when i check the check box it should print the text of it on a text view on the main activity and when i check the other one it should be printed under the first one and if i uncheck one the text should be removed from the text view . and the problem is  i cant get it to show the check box text  inside the text view in the main activity . thank you again :)